# Wait and waitln only work once even when using flushrecv

Tags: teraterm

I am writing a macro for Tera Term to test a microcontroller that is connected to a COM port. I want the macro to pause and wait for a user prompt, but when I use a wait command it works for the first prompt, but does not work for the second prompt.

I have tried to use different keys, CR, F1, even alpha keys to trigger the prompt, but it won't wait at all.

```
clearscreen 0
dispstr 'INSTRUCTIONS_1'
dispstr #13
flushrecv
dispstr 'INSTRUCTIONS_2'
wait #13
flushrecv

sendln 'COMMAND_1'
mpause 250
sendln 'COMMAND_2'
mpause 250
sendln 'COMMAND_3'
mpause 250
sendln 'COMMAND_4'

dispstr 'INSTRUCTIONS_3'
wait #13
flushrecv

sendln 'COMMAND_5'
sendln 'COMMAND_6'

dispstr 'INSTRUCTIONS_4'
wait #13
```

I expect the macro to display instructions for someone doing the testing in the future, then hit enter once they have performed the instructions. The commands are issued to the microcontroller and then the microcontroller does its thing while the macro waits for the user to connect things like an oscilloscope or a continuity checker. The mpause commands are there to give the microcontroller a bit of time to write to memory and to execute the command.

What actually happens is the first two sets of instructions show up and wait for a carriage return. Then the rest of the macro runs without pausing.

EDIT: I found a workaround using yesnobox and message box instead of waiting for a keystroke.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, the wait command is just for what appears in the terminal screen. So if the instructions have a carriage return in them, the wait command will execute because it has received the carriage return, depending on how quickly or synchronously it processes with the dispstr command.

The yesnobox would be a good workaround, but if the people are reading the instructions, I'd be curious if you couldn't just add a short pause (2-3) seconds after your dispstr commands and prior to your wait commands.